# Python List Del & Reconciliation

Tags: python, list, del

I'm trying to delete multiple elements from a list. 
The elements are having their indexes evaluated dynamically, and stored in a list called "dstry". It may look something like this:

```
arr = [1, 2, 2, 3, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 2]
dstry = [1, 2, 9]
```

However, if I do...

```
for i in dstry:
    del arr[i]
```

The list begins to shrink, and `dstry`'s target elements are no longer where they should be. 
Logically, how can I get around this? It'd be nice if the del could resolve all at once and delay the collapse of the array. Should I instead replace the elements with a flag value and then del them wherever they appear later so that index is not a factor?

Thanks

Comment: What is `arr.del`? lists have no `del` method. Do you mean `del arr[i]` ?

Comment: use arr.remove() instead of del()

Comment: Use comprehension: `[a for i, a in enumerate(arr) if i not in dstry]`.

Comment: Reverse `destry` while you loop over it, that way the indices remain faithful: `for i in reversed(dstry): del arr[i]`. That being said, doing it like this is computationally inefficient. The answer in the linked duplicated has a number of superior methods.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A bit creative solution, but this should fix the problem with the index you had.

```
arr = [1, 2, 2, 3, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 2]
dstry = [1, 2, 9]

x=len(arr)

for i in dstry:
    del arr[-x+i]

print(arr)
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. However, remove doesn't serve the proper purpose here as remove is based on the value in the list rather than the index.

Comment: Your current solution only works if `dstry` is sorted from small to large. Just reverse the list, then you don't have to adapt the indices.

Comment: Changed it to what you said.